# prevent automatic UILabel font changes after setting the attributedText

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I've figured out that if I set an attributed text to an `UILabel`, the predefined font will be changed to the font of the first character of attributed text. for example:

```
// the font size is set to 20 in Interface Builder
println(theLabel.font.pointSize);
var styledText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "$100");
var smallFont = UIFont(name: theLabel.font.fontName, size: theLabel.font.pointSize / 2)!;
styledText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: smallFont, range: NSMakeRange(0, 1));
theLabel.attributedText = styledText;
println(theLabel.font.pointSize);
// output:
// 20
// 10
```

I've no idea if it could be called a bug or not, but it causes problem in some cases.

Can anybody suggest a clean solution to obtain the default font that have set in the Interface Builder?

One solution to reset the font to predefined font is to set the `text` property of `UILabel`, because that causes the `UILabel` to switch to the plain text mode (no attributed text anymore).

```
theLabel.text = ""; // reset the font
println(theLabel.font.pointSize);
// output:
// 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Let say that `let myLabel: UILabel` have a font size of 20. *myLabel* should display an attributed text: "foo bar", where "bar" has font size of 30.

If you change the font on *myLabel*, with the intention to change the font size of "foo" to not be 20, but rather 15 instead, you will notice that this results in your `attributedText` being messed up.

Inspired by @Majid's findings, if you set the `text` property before applying the font change. The `attributedText` stays intact, **and now updated with a new "default" font!**

```
func setFont(_ font: UIFont, keepAttributes: Bool = true) {
    // Store attributedText before it gets ruined by font change
    let attributed = attributedText
    if attributed != nil && keepAttributes {
        // This trick enables us to change "default" font for our attributedText.
        text = ""
    }
    // Apply font change
    self.font = font.font
    if keepAttributes {
        // Restore attribute text, now with a new `default` font
        attributedText = attributed
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSMakeRange
```

Is responsible for choosing which characters

```
addAttribute
```

has an effect on. When you set

```
NSMakeRange(0,1)
```

it tells every character from the 0th character to the 1st character to be attributed. Which means only the first character can be attributed. Try setting it to

```
NSMakeRange(0,i)   //or     NSMakeRange(0,1000)
```

I set the alt. option to 1000 because it is an arbitrarily large number giving a guaranteed font change just in case "i" does not work

p.s. the // symbol refers to a helpful hint or comment the previous developers wrote down.